# Female equivalent for "wet dreams"?

Tags: synonyms, terminology, grammatical-gender, feminine

As I understand, the term *wet dreams* applies only to masculine gender? Then, unless it's unisex in nature, is there a specific term applicable to feminine gender?

Comment: This is not a gender-specific term.

Comment: In a literal/biological sense, the phenomenon can only occur in males, so there's no need for a feminine version of the term.

Comment: The same term is used for men and women: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnal_emission

Comment: @Marthaª, why would the phenomenon only be able to occur in males? Women can have ‘wet’ dreams just as well as men can; it is only the mechanism that causes the wetness that differs.

Comment: @MετάEd Well in the article it says that nocturnal emission includes erection and or ejaculation. That doesn't sound right. Having an erection while asleep is not the same as "wetting" yourself or the bed sheets. And the term, *wet dreams*, is traditionally associated with male emissions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "... for a male, or lubrication of the vagina for a female". Quote out of context much?

Comment: @MετάEd quote from Wikipedia. "This section needs more medical references for verification or relies too heavily on primary sources, specifically: some sources are 60 years old and out of date" So even Wikipedia isn't that confident about the *veracity* of the article.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The Wikipedia citation for the claim is a 1999 (updated 2007) Columbia University official health publication. Your concern about sixty-year-old sources makes no sense.

Comment: @MετάEd why does it make no sense? [Studies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_Behavior_in_the_Human_Female) conducted back in 1953 cannot be contested or said to be at least dated? I don't understand, perhaps I am stupid.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The claim that the same medical term is used for men and women does not depend on sexuality studies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As surprising as it may seem to some, women *do* have "wet dreams" or, to use the medical term, [nocturnal emissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnal_emission).

I'll certainly agree that the term is used more often when talking about the male experience, perhaps because there are more obvious physiological signs and the fact that wet dreams are pretty much a part of every teenage boy's growing up.

[Alfred Kinsey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Kinsey) found in his studies that nearly 40% of women interviewed experienced a nocturnal emission, although in women he concluded that the subject *perceived* climax as a result of arousal whereas, in males, climax was obvious.

So, to answer your question, the term "wet dream" is not gender-specific; it's just more common in a male context.